# How to Draw a 3D graph in Matlab for the Data shown below

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to plot and view the data in 3D plane for the data shown below, where the fragment ion is on X axis, amino acid on Y axis and 'Number of Ions' for a particular fragment ion & Amino Acid on Z axis.

```
Fragment Ion    Amino Acid  No of Ions


'b1'           'YY'              1

'b2'           'YF'              7

'b2'           'YE'              3

'b4'           'TV'              4

'b5'           'VS'              11

'b7'           'VK'              10

'b8'           'VL'              7

'b12'          'VK'              9
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question a bit more. not comrehensive.

Comment: Can you add an illustration (even by hand) of the plot you want to make? And how your data looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood you right. I would do it like this:

```
data=importdata('yourdatafile.txt')
fragmentIon=data.textdata(2:end,1)
aminoAcid=data.textdata(2:end,2)
noOfIons=data.data

X=1:length(fragmentIon)
Y=1:length(aminoAcid)
Z=noOfIons

XTickLabels=unique(fragmentIon)
YTickLabels=unique(aminoAcid)

XTicks=1:length(XTickLabels)
YTicks=1:length(YTickLabels)

for i=1:length(fragmentIon)
    X(i)=find(strcmp(XTickLabels,fragmentIon{i}))
    Y(i)=find(strcmp(YTickLabels,aminoAcid{i}))
end

figure
plot3(X,Y,Z,'x')

set(gca,'XTick',XTicks,'XTickLabel',XTickLabels,'YTick',YTicks,'YTickLabel',YTickLabels)
```

[image: Plot Looks like this]